# WTForms add additional categories to SelectField

Tags: python, forms, dynamic, wtforms

I've seen forms like this on the internet before - basically I want to allow the user to dynamically add fields to a SelectField dropdown form in WTForms. For example, maybe the first field in the dropdown menu is a link that allows the user to add custom fields to the form. How would I go about implementing something like this in WTForms? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Michael I know this is 3 months late but I recently did something similar with the help of AngularJS and bootstrap modals so I thought I'll put this up for the sake of completeness:

This is a very simplified version I have not included error checking or validation of any sorts you of course want to do that for your production environment.

In my template the following is what the select field looks like. Instead of the first option being the one to enable a person to create something I just added a link next to the select field that allows a person to add a new category. The link itself opens up a form in a modal.

The following is the select field:

```
<div class="form-group">
        {{ form.maincategory.label(class="col-sm-2 control-label") }}
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ form.maincategory(**{'ng-model':'maincategory',
                                'ng-options':'c.id as c.displayname for c in allmaincategories',
                                'class':'form-control'}) }} 
        #over here is the link that opens the form in a modal window
        </div><a data-toggle="modal" href="#newcategory">Add a new category</a>
    </div>
```

When a user click on the link add new category the following modal window loads:

```
<!-- Add new category Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="newcategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create new main category</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" ng-submit="createCategory()">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ categoryform.displayname.label(class="col-sm-8 control-label") }}
                <div>
                    {{ categoryform.displayname(**{'ng-model':'maincat.displayname','class':'form-control'}) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The WTFORM form class that renders the above form in the modal window is as follows:

```
class DirectoryMainCategoryForm(Form):
    displayname = TextField('Category name as it appears', validators=[DataRequired(message=(u'This category name is how it appears in the menu'))])

#the following is the form main form where the select appears
class MainEntry(Form):
    maincategory = QuerySelectField('Main category', validators = DataRequired(message=(u'Please select a category for this place'))], get_label='category',
    allow_blank=False, query_factory=Maincategory.query.all,blank_text =('-- Select a main category --'))


#And of course the javascript magic that glues it all together:
function DirectoryController($scope, $http){
    #Adds a new category to the select menu
    $scope.createCategory = function() {
        var categorydata = angular.toJson($scope.maincat);
        $http.post('/create/new/category', categorydata).success(function(data) {
            $scope.allmaincategories = data.category;
        });
    }
}
```